# tilting a disc in 3d space - need help

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

Lets imagine you have a disc like a CD. Then you take that CD and rest it flat on a desk. Now you tilt the disc left to right and forward to back while touching the desk with 1 point on the edge of the disc.

-Assume you know the tilt angle forward to back as (y) and the tilt angle left to right as (x). 
-You know the radius of the CD disc as R.
-You know the CD disc rotation angle between the radius of the point touching the desk and the point you want to figure the height for.

Edit//
Angle y is in the yz plane

Angle x is in the xz plane

The the angle between the radius of the 2 points is in the xy plane

//

Id like to know how to determine the height from the desk to any other point on that disc.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually much simpler than that.

You can set up a Cartesian 3D coordinate system where the disc radius is $R$ (diameter $2R$), the desk is at $z = 0$, the center of the disc is at $(0, 0, z_c)$, and the disc touches the desk at $(-x_t, 0, 0)$.  This means the disc is always parallel to the $y$ axis (as if you were to hold the disc up in air using a thin wire at $x = 0$, $z = z_c$).

Then, the vertical distance from any point on the disk is a function of the $x$ coordinate of that point,
$$\bbox[#ffffef]{z = z_c + x \frac{z_c}{x_t} \tag{1}\label{NA1}}$$

Note that even the disc radius is not a factor. This is because the same applies if you had a triangle, or indeed any planar shape that touches the desk at $(-x_t, 0, 0)$, and is angled in the $xz$ plane only (always parallel to the $y$ axis).

This is easy to transform to any other coordinate system you prefer. However, the OP didn't specify any, so I suppose this should suffice.

Comment: I can’t seem to grasp how it is parallel to the y axis if your tilting the disc along 2 axis. I need a bit of an explanation please.

Comment: @DanG. The coordinate system has been chosen so that this is the case. It’s not the same coordinate system that you’re using in your question, though.

Comment: @DanG.: There is no need to use two tilt angles. Instead, rotate the disc so that the point where the disc touches the desk and the center of the disc are both on the $x$ axis.